# Most outgoing connections blocked (kind of?)

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I have a server which I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. Now I have some extremely strange behaviour (which I believe was not present immediately after the upgrade, but can't be sure): I can't (by hostname or by IP) ping, ssh, nslookup, curl or telnet anything, even an address behind the NAT of the router. I can't even ping the gateway, which I know is accepting pings because I pinged it from a box which is physically on the same network.

But here is the weird part: this box is on the other side of the world from me, and I can still ssh **in** to it. Even weirder? I have ipsec and xl2tpd running so that I can VPN in. That works fine too. Most weird? If I route http traffic over the vpn to this box from my computer on the other side of the world, I can browse the internet just fine. And yes, I have shut down these two services and it does not fix the problem.

All of my firewall rules are disabled at the moment:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

and iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

my routes look ok (192.168.0.1 is the correct gateway):

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

and nothing wrong with ifconfig either (IP is correct and DHCP assigned):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:192.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5246:5dff:fe53:975d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13748 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2727272 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:11775785 (11.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:350 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:350 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:33067 (33.0 KB)  TX bytes:33067 (33.0 KB)
```

I... am honestly out of ideas on this one. Can anyone tell me how this could be possible? Or anything else I can check? syslog and dmesg also yield no clues.

Edit: here is what the disconnection looks like:

nslookup:

```
$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$
```

ping:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
<... hangs forever>
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
195 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 195553ms
$
```

ping gateway:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
<... hangs forever>
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
47 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 46361ms
$
```

curl for stackoverflow.com:

```
$ curl 198.252.206.16
<... hangs forever>
^C
$
```

Comment: What happens when you try to make outgoing connections? You forgot that detail, and it's important.

Comment: You're right Michael, that was a bit silly of me. I have added it now.

Comment: please post `iptables-save` output; I've had friend call me not long ago and he had POSTROUTING -j SNAT rule which was rewriting source to static IP he no longer had (dhcp lease changed); also please provide output of `mii-tool`

Comment: aha! the SNAT was it. I will post an answer explaining it further. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Hrvoje Špoljar in the comments above, I have a solution. Turns out that after following [this guide](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_with_Ubuntu_14.04.html), I had the following command in my rc.local:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source %SERVERIP% -o eth+
```

but %SERVERIP% was the wrong IP address. So I had the wrong rule in my iptables. Unfortunately, ufw on ubuntu "protects" you from seeing these more advanced rules as you can see in my iptables output above. On the other hand, if you run the iptables-save command, you get the following:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Nov 14 21:19:16 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [318:73010]
:INPUT ACCEPT [64:6615]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [100:7122]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [48:2941]
-A POSTROUTING -s XX.XX.XX.XX/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j SNAT --to-source YY.YY.YY.YY
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 14 21:19:16 2014
```

where `YY.YY.YY.YY` is the incorrect ip address. The fix is to delete this rule with

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth+ -j SNAT --to-source YY.YY.YY.YY
```

and use instead the much more DHCP friendly:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

where 10.1.1.0/24 is the ip address range that the VPN clients are given.

Comment: It's not hiding it, you just have to look into the correct table:

iptables -t nat -L -n -v 

will show it.